# Is it possible to display a PopupWindow from within another PopupWindow?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, popupwindow

In a Honeycomb application, I am in several places using a custom subclass of PopupWindow to display various views. This all works great until one of those views happens to try to display another PopupWindow.

For example, Spinner and AutoCompleteTextView both use PopupWindow to display their associated lists of choices. If you put one of these in a PopupWindow's view, and click to activate the widget, the WindowManager will warn you via LogCat:

`WARN/WindowManager(111): Attempted to add window with token that is a sub-window: android.os.BinderProxy@40ea6880.  Aborting.`

And then it will throw a `WindowManager$BadTokenException` when it actually tries to show that PopupWindow.

The view for the custom PopupWindow is being inflated using a LayoutInflater obtained from the anchor view's Context. I have seen other questions suggesting that BadTokenExceptions can occur when using an inappropriate Context to get a LayoutInflater, but it doesn't seem like there is another option in this case.

The Log warning from WindowManager seems to indicate that this is an unsupported case. Can anyone confirm this, or provide a stick to poke me in the right direction?

Here's a link to the code (some version of it, anyway) from which the error case originates: [WindowManagerService.java](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/services/java/com/android/server/WindowManagerService.java&q=Attempted%20to%20add%20window%20with%20token%20that%20is%20a%20sub-window&type=cs&l=1823)

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm too trying to obtain the similar thing

Comment: No luck. I believe it to be fundamentally impossible, so I switched to using Dialogs or Dialog-themed Activities where I was previously using PopupWindow and required the sub-window functionality.

Comment: Me too. I converted my Popup to Activity with Trasparent theme to achieve what I needed.

Comment: @lyricsboy i post the answer if you still keen on knowing it ;)

Comment: @KiranParmar i post the answer if you still keen on knowing it ;)

Answer (score -1):

for sure you can display a **PopupWindow** from within another **PopupWindow**, just create a new pop_up window variable and *inflate* the new **PopupWindow layout** in a new *view*, just like in the following example:

```
public PopupWindow pw;
public PopupWindow new_pw;
public View pw_layout = null;
public View new_pw_layout = null;

public void initiatePopupWindow() throws Exception{
// to get the instance of the LayoutInflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) YourCurrentActivityClass.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

pw_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_popup_xml,
                    (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.first_popup_main_layout));

// create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
pw = new PopupWindow(pw_layout,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
// display the popup in the center
pw.showAtLocation(pw_layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

Button item_button = (Button) pw_layout.findViewById(R.id.item);
                item_button .setOnClickListener(onItemlClick);

}


// the onClick listener for the item button
public OnClickListener onItemlClick = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

if(v == item_button){
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) YourCurrentActivityClass.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
new_pw_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_popup_xml,
                    (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.second_popup_main_layout));
// create a 300px width and 470px height new PopupWindow
new_pw = new PopupWindow(new_pw_layout,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
// display the new popup in the center
new_pw.showAtLocation(new_pw_layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);// you can set it's position here([0,0] means in the exact center it's like [go 0 pixels from the center to the right , go 0 pixels from the center down])

}
}
};
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the precise question. Your example code is showing two PopupWindows, but they are both inflated via your Activity. The first PopupWindow does not, in your case, contain the second PopupWindow's view. The example scenario in my question relates to a framework View (like Spinner) trying to show a PopupWindow (for the list of items) within a PopupWindow that I created and showed.

Comment: they both inflated from the main activity but the second pop_up is shown only by the processing of the first pop_up(like pressing a button on that pop_up) and the second pop_up will be displayed over the first pop_up.